# Is the default hypervisor is LXC and how do I change it to KVM?

Tags: juju, openstack, lxc

Is the default hypervisor is LXC, when i install my openstack with juju (`sudo openstack-install`)?

How to change it to KVM? Except the array of EMC, how to use the third array through cinder?

Or just how to make my services become bare-metal service or LXC service?

All my problems seem to be that I can't write the config.yaml file flexibly.